# Delete all words with ONLY & JUST 2 capital letters

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

Good day,

I was wondering how to delete all words with just two capital letters.

So far I have done:

```
sed 's/[A-Z][A-Z]//g'
```

**Input**

```
AB, cd, EFG, hIJk, L, mnoPQ, rSt, UVxy
```

**Output**

```
, cd, EFG, hIJk, L, mnoPQ, rSt, UVxy
```

Thanks in advance for any clue

Comment: So does that include 'hIJk' ?

Comment: Is "AB, cd, EFG, hIJk, L, mnoPQ, rSt" a possibility?
i.e. two capital letters before a comma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there. Just add the word boundaries to the both sides of the regex :

```
sed 's/\b[A-Z][A-Z]\b//g'
```

**Update:** (suggested by user ***CodeGnome***)

To make this work on BSD systems like OS X, you'd need to change the word boundaries and invoke sed with the -E flag. For example:

```
sed -E 's/[[:<:]][A-Z][A-Z][[:>:]]//g'
```

Comment: Thank so much for your time, you are right and you have just show me something new of sed. Have a good day ( :

Comment: My pleasure. Actually it's a part of `regex` syntax not particularly belongs to `sed`.

Comment: This only works with GNU sed. It won't work with BSD sed as written.

Comment: @CodeGnome : Thanks for the info. To be frank I've never used a `BSD` system till date.

Comment: To make this work on BSD systems like OS X, you'd need to change the word boundaries and invoke sed with the -E flag. For example: `sed -E 's/[[:<:]][A-Z][A-Z][[:>:]]//g'`

Comment: @CodeGnome : would you mind if I add it my answer, or better u update your answer.

Comment: Go ahead and add it. I'd rather see you with a comprehensive answer. Glad to help!

Answer (score 2):

### Ruby One-Liner

```
echo 'AB, cd, EFG, hIJk, L, mnoPQ, rSt, UVxy' |
ruby -ne 'puts $_.split(?,).
          map(&:strip).
          reject { |word| word =~ /\A\p{Upper}{2}\z/ }.
          join ", "'
```

### Result

```
cd, EFG, hIJk, L, mnoPQ, rSt, UVxy
```

Comment: Thank so much for your time and showing me how ruby works. But you weren't the first. Have a good day ( :

Answer (score 1):

What about :

```
echo "AB, cd, EFG, hIJk, L, mnoPQ, rSt, UVxy" | sed  's/^[A-Z][A-Z]\([^A-Z]\)/\1/' |sed 's/\([^A-Z]\)[A-Z][A-Z]$/\1/' |sed  's/\([a-z0-9]\)[A-Z][A-Z]\([a-z0-9]\)/\1\2/g'
```

the output is

**, cd, EFG, hk, L, mnoPQ, rSt, UVxy**

Comment: Thank so much for your time. It works :D . The only 'but' is that your proposal is just non-practical. Have a good day : )

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\<[A-Z][A-Z]\>//g' file
```

most probably works for all variations of sed.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "AB, cd, EFG, hIJk, L, mnoPQ, rSt, UVxy" | \
 sed 's/.*/ & /;s/\([^a-zA-Z]\)[A-Z]\{2\}\([^A-Za-z]\)/\1\2/g;s/.\(.*\)./\1/'
```

should do the trick for posix version (`--posix` on GNU sed)